# ajax json response containing html

Tags: php, html, ajax

Do I need to json_encode ajax response data before sending?

```
$html1 = '<span>some html</span>';
$html2 = '<span>some html</span>';
$res = array('html1'=>$html1, 'html2'=>$html2);
echo json_encode($res);
```

or

```
echo $res;
```

Comment: Is this `php`..?

Comment: @TJ yes , I have updated question

Comment: One of the very basics of PHP is that you can't `echo` an array, so yes, you would need to JSON encode it if that's the form in which you wish to return it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The X in AJAX stands for XML

If you return XHTML, you do not need to json_encode it

```
echo '<div>'.$html1.$html2.'</div>';
```

You can

1. dump it onto the page `someElement.innerHTML = returnValue;` or `document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend',returnValue);`
2. Extract from a DOMFragment:

---

```
const domFragMent = document.createElement("div")
domFragment.innerHTML = returnValue;
const spans = domFragment.querySelectorAll("span");
```

3. use a [domParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)
4. Send a json_encoded array of values and parse them on the client into spans

Comment: I need to work with the returned code separately in jquery. So for example using data.html1

Comment: @qqmisko You can still parse the response regardless of it being XML or JSON?

Comment: @maio290 thank you. How would I parse such XHTML response?

Comment: And even if you want to parse it, [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) got you covered.